# What file mode, access and share is used in php's file_get_contents

Tags: c#, php, windows, file, readfile

In *C# on Windows* `File.Open()` method has the following function definition:

`File.Open(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)`

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Where the parameters can have the following values:

- **FileMode**: Append, Create, CreateNew, Open, OpenOrCreate, Truncate
- **FileAccess**: Read, ReadWrite, Write
- **FileShare**: Delete, Inheritable, None, Read, ReadWrite, Write

## Main question

Which FileMode, FileAccess and FileShare is used for `file_get_contents` in php on Windows?

### Side question 1

How can FileAccess and FileShare be influenced for `file_get_contents` or `fopen` in php on Windows?

### Side question 2

Can two or more concurrent processes on windows use `file_get_contents` for the same file?

Thank you very much in advance.